# How to groupColumn in .xlsx files using POI 3.6?

Tags: java, xls, apache-poi, xlsx

I recently switched from POI 3.1 (HSSF) to POI 3.6 (XSSF) and encountered a problem.

The problem is that the `groupColumn` no longer works as expected!

Does anyone know why the column grouping works properly only BEFORE writing in the cells from the worksheet and does not work well AFTER the worksheet is written?

Is there a way to group columns on an xlsx file **after** writing data in the column's cells?

Thank you very much,
Gabriela

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem. The following code works fine for my purposes:

```
     for ( int index = groupingRange.getFirstColumn() + 1; index <= groupingRange.getLastColumn() + 1; index++ ) {
        CTCols[] colsArray = targetSheet.getCTWorksheet().getColsArray();

        colSearch: for ( int i = 0; i < colsArray.length; i++ ) {
           CTCol[] colArray = colsArray[i].getColArray();
           for ( int j = 0; j < colArray.length; j++ ) {
              if ( index == colArray[j].getMin() ) {
                 colArray[j].setOutlineLevel((short)(colArray[j].getOutlineLevel() + 1));
                 colArray[j].setCollapsed(true);
                 colArray[j].setHidden(true);

                 index = (int)colArray[j].getMax();
                 break colSearch;
              }
           }
        }
     }
```

Best
Olaf